# Warning RequestContextHolder has a NULL RequestContext when calling an oauth API

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to call an oauth API, this call gets made by my main API internally,

I have created a resttemplate class -

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Configuration
public class MonkeyRestTemplate {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(env.getRequiredProperty("monkey.api.accessToken.url"));
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId(env.getRequiredProperty("monkey.api.client.id"));
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret(env.getRequiredProperty("monkey.api.client.secret"));
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientCredentialsResourceDetails);
    }

}
```

and here's my controller class -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/monkeyinfo")
public class MonkeyApiService {

@Autowired
private MonkeyRestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth2", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers="Accept=application/json" )
public MonkeyMain getProducts(@RequestBody String holder) {

    ResponseEntity<MonkeyMain> forEntity = oauth2RestTemplate.oauth2RestTemplate().getForEntity(env.getProperty("monkey.bananainfo.POST.uri"),
            MonkeyMain.class);
     System.out.println(forEntity.getBody());
    return forEntity.getBody();
}
}
```

`MonkeyMain.class` is my main model class to Marshall/Unmarshall Json body.

but when this API gets called, I am getting following warning with `403 forbidden` Status -

```
Warning RequestContextHolder has a NULL RequestContext, therefore we are returning a NullRequestContext, therefore not all features may work as desired.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Please guide.